# Can I set texture from several images?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I want to set texture to CCBatchNode from several images due to image size limitation.
Can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean sprite sheets? Like this: http://www.zwopple.com/zwoptex/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. A batchnode uses a single texture only, and textures have a technical size limit, usually 2048x2048 or 4096x4096 on newer devices.

Comment: Thanks. My sprite sheet's size is larger than 4096. I'll try to use several textures to one animation.

Comment: 4kx4k texture with 32bit color consumes 64 MB memory (unless PVRTC compressed), keep that in mind! On iPad 1 you couldn't even load 2 of those, on iPad 2 you may be able to squeeze in 3 perhaps. Whatever you plan on doing it sounds like you're overdoing it.

Comment: OK, I will take into consideration for trying TexturePacker or reduce image resolution and scale up in program.
Thanks again for everything.